# Cannot assign object literal to `...` because property `...` is missing in object literal [1] but exists in `...`

Tags: flowtype

I am new flow and currently working on a project with flow strict. I have a type alias being passed to a class. The snippet can be found [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHdQGcAuAnAlgYxQKFwKYAeADrGiqCgJ4kGgDCArqrALYAqt9AvKAN65QoAIYAuZOgwA7AOYAaIaABGE5bFjQCI6YuFY1GrTr2gAJoc3bdSgpePTcAXwDcuLZTOg+6JgTceKt5UaH4BBJRYLCjsXHRizKyc3MGCwunpZqYZwsrZOQYhfnpO+FjQIkhIjNHsaaBYsNKooTjkABRRSXG8Ak4AlH3O+IFdMWzB0gSIieOdtcl0-S5AA)

```
// @flow strict

export type CustomType = {
  a: string,
  b: boolean,
  c: boolean,
  d: boolean,
  e: boolean
};
let d = true;
let b = true;
let customType:CustomType = {
        d,
        b,
        c: true,
 }

class Custom{
  constructor(customType = {}) {}
}

let custom = new Custom(customType);
```

When passing the object not all properties customType are present. What is the best fix here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could type the keys of the `CustomType` object as [optional](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-optional-object-type-properties):

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHdQGcAuAnAlgYxQKFwKYAeADrGiqCgJ4kGgDCArqrALYAqt9AvKAN65QoAIYB+AFzJ0GAHYBzADRDQAI0lrYsaARGzlwrBtVadeg6AAmx07v0qCN7XdwBfANy4dlS6D7omAk9vNT8qNEDggkosFhR2LjopZlZObjDBYSysywts4VU8-KwpAIIDV3wsaBEkJEY49kzQLFhZVAiccgAKWNTEgmTGtLoM1wBKAUrKr2iW4bDZAkQU+LZe4YHx9yA))

```
// @flow strict

export type CustomType = {
  a?: string,
  b?: boolean,
  c?: boolean,
  d?: boolean,
  e?: boolean
};
let d = true;
let b = true;
let customType: CustomType = {
        d,
        b,
        c: true,
 }

class Custom{
  constructor(customType: CustomType = {}) {}
}

let custom = new Custom(customType);
```

Alternatively, you could use `$Shape<T>`. It lets you only pass the keys you're interested in:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHdQGcAuAnAlgYxQKFwKYAeADrGiqCgJ4kGgDCArqrALYAqt9AvKAN65QoAIYAuZOgwA7AOYAaIaABGE5bFjQCI6YuFY1GrTr2gAJoc3bdSgpePTcAXwDcuLZTOg+6JgTceKt5UaH4BBJRYLCjsXHQSACQAygAWInQAPMysnNwAfMGCwsXFZqYlwsrlFQYhfnpO+FjQIkhIjNHsRaBYsNKooTjkABRROXF2oMlpmdkxuXQFfPxOAJQCjY3uET2dbMHSBIhz7KN7E6suQA))

```
// @flow strict

export type CustomType = {
  a: string,
  b: boolean,
  c: boolean,
  d: boolean,
  e: boolean
};
let d = true;
let b = true;
let customType: $Shape<CustomType> = {
        d,
        b,
        c: true,
 }

class Custom{
  constructor(customType: $Shape<CustomType> = {}) {}
}

let custom = new Custom(customType);
```

Comment: The downside of $Shape is losing intellisense